# Query group policy remotely

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is there a programmatic way to remotely query a Windows AD from Linux to see if a group policy is in effect for a remote machine?

My set up is as follows

[image: Basic Setup]

I would like to know if I can query the AD (using anything e.g. remote script) about the policies being applied to the workstation

Comment: Maybe [Powershell remoting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-6)?

Comment: @HarryJohnston that does seem like the approach :P I was hoping for a lower-level approach but will go with this for now.